# For Good coding practice, do we still have to validate data again in method2 if we already validated in method1 & method1 passes that data to method2?

Tags: c#, java, php, c++, validation

Let say I have

```
public void method1(){
    String s1="";
    String s1=getText();
    if(MyValidation.isOk(s1)){
       dosomethingWith s1 here
       then
       method2(s1);
    }
}

public void method1(String s1){
    if(MyValidation.isOk(s1)){ // do we need this line of code??
        //do something
    }
}
```

For Good coding practice,

do we still have to validate data again in method2 if we already validated it in method1 & method1 passes that data to method2?

Comment: The answer depends.  Is `method2` isolated in such away as to make it impossible for it to be called before `method1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code to isolate the internal methods that assume the data is good from the exposed public methods that execute the validation on the external inputs.
Of course, if you screw up your data in the internal methods then it is your problem

```
public void method1(){
    String s1="";
    String s1=getText();
    if(MyValidation.isOk(s1)){
       RunSomethingInternalForMethod1(s1);
       // or
       // if(RunSomethingInternalForMethod1(s1))
       //     RunSomethingInternalForMethod2(s1);
    }
}

public void method2(String s1){
    if(MyValidation.isOk(s1)){ 
        RunSomethingInternalForMethod2(s1);
    }
}

// PRIVATE HERE ... NO WAY TO CALL THIS FROM CODE EXTERNAL TO THIS CLASS
private void RunSomethingInternalForMethod1(string s1){
    .....
    // You could call the additional internal code here, or add this 
    // call after the public method1, you could even change the return value
    // of this method and call the second one only if this one is successful
    RunSomethingInternalForMethod2(s1);
}
private void RunSomethingInternalForMethod2(string s1){

}
```

Another approach, but I really cannot recommend it because it leads to complex state is through the use of a global class level boolean variable that contains the result of the validation. I repeat myself, just in case your validations are complex and expensive to repeat (a simple null check is not an expensive operation)

```
public Class Test
{
     private bool _validatedOK = false;

     public void method1()
     {

         if(!_validatedOK) 
              _validatedOK = MyValidation.isOk(s1);
         if{_validatedOK)
         {
              ......
              method2();
         }
     }
     public void method2()
     {

         if(!_validatedOK) 
              _validatedOK = MyValidation.isOk(s1);
         if{_validatedOK)
         {
              .....
         }
     }
}
```

As you can see this approach doesn't repeat the validation for the same instance of the class.

Comment: but even if it's private, u not sure someone won't use pass unchecked data to that method. Ex, I & my friend maybe  sharing the same computer & all coding the same Class, if my friend call that private method in that class then he can have a problem if he won't check. So how to deal with that?

Comment: Of course this is a problem, but the tampering is limited to code from your own class not from external methods. So it should be easy to control what happens. It is one of the principle of OOP to hide the implementation details to avoid difficult to track bugs

Comment: so we can't guarantee for sure if 2 people working on the same class, do u figure out another way

Comment: what if the same person misuse the private method forgot that that method has no Validation

Comment: No way to prevent it AFAIK. Depending on the complexity of your validation code and the context in which you call this code this could be a false problem. If it is just a check for null or empty then repeat the validation. Otherwise, you could add a boolean (bool ValidatedOK) at the global class level that you set initially to false in the constructor or in the public methods and to true when the validation succeed. You check the variable in the internal methods without repeating the validation. But I don't reccomend this because you could never be sure of the code paths used

Comment: And I haven't talked about reflection.

Answer (score 5):

Since it's a public method, there's no guarantee that method1(string) is ONLY EVER going to be called from method1() is there?

Answer (score 0):

What if your `method2` will be called by other methods?

In general when you make a certain method `public` you can never be sure that your method will be called only by certain callers and put a validation only on the callers.

So all in all you need to have a validation inside to make sure that whoever will call your method will not end up with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you already validated the data in your method1 and there is no chance that the data could be modified in between the calls to method2 ,
then there is no need to validate it again.

According to the edited question, if you are modifying the data after validation in `method1` then you must validate it again in `method2` under special circumstances

ex
                **Case 1**

```
  public void method1(string s)
  {
        if(s!=null)
        {
            // do something with s here. 
            // but not make it null
            method2(s) ; 
        }
  }
  public void method2(string s)
  {
          // do something with s
  }
```

In the above case, even if you don't check `s` in `method2` it wiil create no problem unless `method2` is called from other methods

**Case2**

```
     public void method1(string s)
     {
        if(s!=null)
        {
            // do something with s here. 
             String temp = s ; 
             s = null ; 
             method2(s) ; 
        }
  }
      public void method2(string s)
      {
            // do something with s
       }
```

In case2 , it can be dangerous if you don't check the condition in `method2`.

In anycase, my advice will be to check for the condition in both the methods only iff the conditions needs to be checked ie there is a chance that `method2` could be called with invalid input from other sources

Comment: i modified my quest a bit, the s1 is used to do something in method1 so we need to validate it int method1